# Deploy elixir phoenix application to heroku - Can not add buildpack

Tags: heroku, elixir, web-deployment, phoenix-framework

So I am trying to deploy my Elixir phoenix web application to Heroku. I am following this guide: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/heroku.html

But when I get to the point where I need to add a buildpack:

> heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static.git

I get this error:

> Couldn't find that app.

Comment: Have you tried:
`git remote rm heroku`
`git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:yourappname.git`

Comment: Now it says - "No app specified"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: did you respect the order? im just using https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir.git for my REST API and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `heroku buildpacks:add --help` precises that the app parametes is required, so let's check the list of app names:

```
user@machine:~/project> heroku apps
=== john@doe.com Apps
some-app-name (eu)
```

Then re-run the command as such:

```
user@machine:~/project> heroku buildpacks:add <buildpack> --app some-app-name
```